# Android Bitmap странно ест память

Tags: android, java

Когда я создаю картинку примерно 2000х2000 пикселей она занимает в куче примерно 15Мб. Когда я создаю 1500х2000 она занимает примерно 12Мб.

Но когда я создаю более чем 2000х2000 в DDMS почему-то показывается что максимальный однобайтовый объект занимает 1Мб. Хотя сама куча довольно сильно увеличивается и работа с картинкой нареканий не вызывает.

Почему DDMS выдает 1Мб ??

[image]

Comment: Насколько я помню, при некоторых условиях, применяется оптимизация — контент `Bitmap`'а помещается в `shadow heap`, который, соответственно, не засчитывается в `application heap`. При каких условиях и что именно происходит — полагаю, только в сорцах андроида читать, в документации вряд ли.

Comment: какие могут быть нюансы ? например на работу recycle это надеюсь не влияет?

Comment: Нет, не должно, ведь `recycle`, фактически, ничего и не делает, кроме как помечает `pixel data` `Bitmap`'а как `dead` и помогает таким образом GC при его следующем вызове.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария:

Насколько я помню, при некоторых условиях, применяется оптимизация — контент `Bitmap` помещается в *shadow heap*, который, соответственно, не засчитывается в *application heap*.
При каких условиях и что именно происходит — полагаю, только в сорцах андроида читать, в документации вряд ли.

На работу `recycle` это никак не влияет, так как `recycle`, фактически, ничего и не делает, кроме как помечает `pixel data Bitmap` как `dead` и помогает таким образом *GC* при его следующем вызове.

Answer (score 1):

У битмап есть ограничение в использовании памяти,  если картинка превышает объем памяти пула, то вылет с ошибкой. Решается это путем шифрования или перевода в текстов. Файл или же так -http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/139717/